# Alternate to hasColumn in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I cannot find the Schema facade in Laravel 7.  Is it removed ?
I am trying to check for existence of a table column in HomeController

```
Schema::hasColumn('users', 'mainview')
```

but it returns an empty string.
Is there any single line alternate for this.

UPDATE :
Here is my HomeController code :

```
$rslt = Schema::hasColumn('users', 'mainview');
info($rslt);
if (!$rslt) {
  $addcol = DB::statement('alter table users add column mainview tinyint(1)');
}
```

and the Log file is :

```
[2020-07-07 16:56:30] local.INFO:   
[2020-07-07 16:56:30] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'mainview'....
```

Comment: It is still available, as you can see [here](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Schema.html).

Comment: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema` still exists in Laravel 7.

Comment: Then what is wrong in my code.  I have already included the use schema statement in my controller